# How to identify SMD devices from the codes on top of the component?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I have a PCB and I am trying to identify a couple of the ICs and other SMD devices that are on there but can't find anything on or offline that tells me what the package codings mean.

I have a couple of pictures of the components that are of particular interest to me and if anyone could:

1. Help identify these components and,
2. Tell me a way I would be able to try and figure it out in the future?

I have tried a number of websites and none of them have really offered much help for any of these components below...

[image]
codes are: KT3 (SOT23) [top left], CVL (two pin) [bottom left], not sure of the right hand side one. Could either be 1P+backwards K, or Kd+upside down 1, or the K could be an x - it really is not clear, even under a microscope)

[image]
This is slightly clearer and is A48 I believe - no luck on this one either. I imagine it is some sort of single op-amp but again, I can find nothing.

Any help on this and a source of information for this type of question would be great!

Answer (score 6):

1. [KT3](http://www.diodes.com/datasheets/ds12004.pdf) is a BAS21 diode.  Link goes to the data sheet, includes information on similar diodes (BAS19/BAS20/BAS21) and the date code (yours seems to be July 2007)
2. [CVL](http://smdcode.com/en/smd/code/cvl-smcj150c-transient-voltage-supressor-73996/) seems to be a transient voltage suppressor.  The link goes to a site with lots of SMD codes.
3. [A48](http://smdcode.com/en/smd/code/search/?q=A48) could be one of several things.  You'll need to compare the connections of your chip to the datasheets of the various parts that may be marked A48 (most likely a voltage regulator.)
4. [1PX](http://smdcode.com/en/smd/code/search/?q=1px) looks like its a voltage detector.

For the 1PX, the dot shows pin 1.  Putting Pin1 at the lower left mean you read it 1PX instead of other combinations you tried (K and stuff.)

Sorry, I can't give you any really good tips for finding the codes.
The linked site helps, and there are others like it, but it all comes down to having good google-fu.
Google, get ideas, check the circuit against the datasheets.

Answer (score 2):

Google "smd marking code". You can find a bunch of pages. For example: [www.s-manuals.com/smd](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd)