# identifying a SMD chip: A44 66P2

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I have a handful of these chips and I'm trying to figure out what they are. [This post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/176756/how-to-identify-smd-devices-from-the-codes-on-top-of-the-component) links to two sites, smdcode and s-manuals. The former is dead and the latter only classifies A44 as perhaps a transistor. Google wasn't helpful either. Can you help out?

The two lines of codes are just `A44` and `66P2`. No logo. It has 8 pins total.

Blurry pic below. Since it's so generic/unbranded I don't think digging out the fancy camera gear changes anything. Body dimensions are 3.1 x 2.8 x 0.86 mm.

[image: smd pic]

Comment: Can you add a picture of it? What is the package?

Comment: It's just a SO-8. I can add a pic but it's very generic.

Comment: @tedder42 - "*It's just a SO-8*" The new information that it's an SO-8 is helpful, as it eliminates a possibility I was considering, which has an A44 marking but *only* on a much smaller type of 8-pin package, and *not* on it's SO-8 (SOIC-8) package. If these ICs are not soldered to PCB (where we could get at least an *idea* about their possible function by looking at the connections to nearby components), then it's more difficult to identify them. P.S. Now you've added a photo & dimensions, that doesn't look like an SO-8 (it's too small) - more like an MSOP-8. Good luck!

Comment: You're right, SO is too big. I have a few dozen of them on tape, no context.

Answer (score 3):

One possible match is the [OPA2244](http://www.ti.com/product/OPA2244) op-amp from TI (was Burr-Brown) - or a <strike>counterfeit</strike> clone version of it.

According to its [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2244.pdf), it is available in the MSOP-8 package and that package would have top mark `A44` (with TI saying that there "may be additional marking", which could explain the second line).

TI refer to the MSOP-8 package as VSSOP and you see it as package code DGK in the datasheet.

[image: Edited package info (to fit screen width) showing A44 top mark]

(*Excerpt from TI datasheet, edited to fit screen width, confirming A44 top mark for OPA2244 op-amp in that package*)

As you may know, there are counterfeit versions of some other Burr-Brown op-amps. I haven't seen a genuine example in an MSOP-8 package, so I can't say whether your package markings look genuine or not.

Of course, as discussed in the earlier comments, without having any context to examine from the device being "in-circuit", this might be completely the wrong device identifier for your component. If you can afford to sacrifice one of them in the name of testing, you could solder one to a breakout board *as if* it's an OPA2244, add suitable support components and give it a try :-)

---

Update:

*Bruce Abbott* kindly found a *very* similar image to the photo in the question, from a [seller on Alibaba](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/IC-OPA2244EA-msop8-OPA2244EA-OPA2244-A44_60539310588.html) who claims to be selling OPA2244 op-amps:

[image: Image claiming to be OPA2244 op-amps from Alibaba seller]

[Source](http://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1VsoPNpXXXXb8XXXX760XFXXX6/IC-OPA2244EA-msop8-OPA2244EA-OPA2244-A44.png)

This adds further evidence that the combination of those markings, on that package, could be OPA2244 op-amps (or a clone).

Comment: http://sc02.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1VsoPNpXXXXb8XXXX760XFXXX6/IC-OPA2244EA-msop8-OPA2244EA-OPA2244-A44.png

Comment: @Bruce - Thanks Bruce, good find! Since that image is from Alibaba, I'm not *sure* that the ICs are genuine :-) However the seller claims they are OPA2244 op-amps and the markings look very similar, so it's further evidence that the OP's devices might indeed be that op-amp. I'll update my answer to include that image. Thanks again for finding it!

Comment: Counterfeit? There's no marking suggesting they were made by BB or TI. The word is clone.

Comment: @Passerby - Thanks. The counterfeit Burr-Brown op-amps I remember were in a larger package and did have a fake BB or TI logo. However I couldn't find any evidence that even a genuine TI OPA2244 in MSOP-8 would have their logo on the top (lack of space?). Therefore, until we know what a genuine device of that type in that package looks like,  I don't know if we can tell the difference between a genuine part, or one which is *pretending* to be a TI original, but isn't. Anyway, I'm happy to use "clone" - as long as the possibility that they *might* not be the original device is mentioned. Thanks!